# WebSocket connection.send only fires once

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I have a simple websocket chat app consisting of three files: `server.js`, `index.html`, and `client.js`. The html is two input boxes and a send button, but the send button stops working after the first click. I know the event handler is not the issue because it consistently works if I remove `connection.send`. Here's the code:

server.js

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log("New connection");

  ws.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(`New message: ${data}`)
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

client.js

```
 
connection.onopen = (event) => {
  console.log("WebSocket is open now.");
};

connection.onclose = (event) => {
  console.log("WebSocket is closed now.");
};

connection.onerror = (event) => {
  console.error("WebSocket error observed:", event);
};

connection.onmessage = (event) => {
  const chat = document.querySelector('.chat');
  chat.innerHTML += event.data;
}

const button = document.querySelector('#send');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click');
  const name = document.querySelector('#name');
  const message = document.querySelector('#message');
  const data = `<p>${name.value}: ${message.value}</p>`

  connection.send(data); // Removing this line makes it work

  name.value = "";
  message.value = "";
})
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="chat">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="message" id="message">
    <button id="send">Send</button>
  </div>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `chat.innerHTML += event.data`, you make a new button that doesn't have the click event listener.

You can make a separate div to add your extra stuff, or add the click event listener every time you add stuff, or add the extra stuff using `appendChild()` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: That was it, moving the button out of the .chat div fixed it. Thanks!